# Fetch Alexa Rank of Website consistently with PHP

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit

I developed a site and i need to query the Alexa rank of any requested website.
The code works for sometime and stops working for some days too.
This is my code

```
 $url = 'http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=example.com';
 $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
 var_dump($xml);
```

What it returned

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(4) { ["VER"]=> string(3) "0.9" ["URL"]=> string(10) "alexa.com/" ["HOME"]=> string(1) "0" ["AID"]=> string(1) "=" } ["RLS"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["TITLE"]=> string(13) "Related Links" ["PREFIX"]=> string(7) "http://" ["more"]=> string(1) "0" } ["RL"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["HREF"]=> string(77) "www.alexa.com/blocker?tag=YpxpmjmpvjvxjUjxj=0000000000000&ref=data.alexa.com/" ["TITLE"]=> string(41) "Please click here to continue using Alexa" } } } }
```

But sometimes, it actually returns a longer string with data and am able to get what i want from the data array. But after some more queries, it goes back to this result above

Please how can i always get alexa to return the right results, As my website totally depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to query alexa.com would be via its Web Information Service (see also [Is Alexa's data available via an API?](https://support.alexa.com/hc/en-us/articles/200450214-Is-Alexa-s-data-available-via-an-API-)).

As usual, you need to sign up for it and retrieve an API key to be able to query their API (cf. the [introductory section](https://awis.alexa.com/) on their website). They provide a lot of examples on how to use their service, so make sure to read the [docs](https://awis.alexa.com/developer-guide), especially those parts about sending the right headers.

For pricing information, consult their [FAQs](https://awis.alexa.com/faq) and the corresponding [AWS marketplace page](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07Q71HJ3H) - the first 1000 API calls per month are apparently free of charge, which should suffice for at least some proof-of-concept code.